# Just format Dell Inspiron 3521, no network driver works for wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, drivers, dell-inspiron

I just format my computer (Dell Inspiron 3521) and for some reason, after entering my service tag into the dell support website to download drivers, none of the ones shown to me work for the wireless card.

I've tried them all, installed all of the chipset drivers, everything else works fine except the wifi adapter. Please help! Any idea how can I fix this? When I open device manager, the only thing that shows unidentified is a Network Controller which I assume is the wireless adapter, however no use on any of the drivers provided by dell on their website.

[image: Here's the hardware ID]

**EDIT**

Here's a picture showing the error:

[image: Here's the error on the image]

Comment: Within `Device Manager`, can you `Double Click` on your `Network Controller`, go to the `Details` tab, go to the `Hardware IDs` dropdown and post the details from the first line? Need to know the `VEN_` and `DEV_` ID's.

Comment: just use connect via ethernet and Windows should be able to identify your wireless adapter and install its driver from windows update if it doesn't then use hardware id to manually find and download proper driver.

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ that doens't happen, sadly.

Comment: @Jonno editing post to show the hardware id

Comment: @CPC Your error looks like you may have chosen the wrong download - Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit windows, and did you download the correct package for it?

Answer (score 0):

The card is an AR95XX series unit, otherwise branded as Dell Wireless 1707, drivers for either should work.

Make sure you've enabled the Wifi with the correct FN+?? Key Combination / Dedicated switch or the chip can not power up.

Comment: downloading, I'll let you know as soon as I install, reboot and get it working. Just curious, how did you find out exactly this information? By using hardware ID? Where and how?

Comment: @CPC there are plenty of lookup sites but all you need to do is google the important bit of the string "168C&DEV_0036"

Comment: This is not the one. Edited post with picture showing the error

Comment: @CPC You're most likely installing a 32bit driver on a 64bit system, or vice versa, or using a Win7 driver on Win10. The Device is right, its just the wrong compilation of the driver.

Comment: I currently have windows 8.1, just realized the version was windows 7 64bit, still, downloaded the windows 8.1 64bit version (says it's for latitute and vostro, not inspiron like mine, but still went ahead and got the windows 8.1 64bit dell wireless 1707 driver) and when it begins installing, it stays stucked. I'ts been about an hour or more since the program has been stuck like that, it's the second time it happens, dunno what's wrong -_-

Comment: I have the same problem! Any idea what might be wrong with this?